# Removal of link using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replacewith

I am trying to do a very simple task but I cannot seem to figure it out. I am trying to write a function that will remove a link without removing the text associated with it. Here are the specifics:

```
<a href="../../../../articles/c/a/t/Special%7ECategories_101d.html" title="Special:Categories">Categories</a>[/CODE]
```

I am trying to remove everything EXCEPT the text "Categories", I just want to remove the href tag. I would even be willing to rename the title "Categories". I just want to link gone. This link is in a div called "mw-normal-catlinks" and it is the first link in the `div`. I do not want to remove the other content in that `div`.

I am very new to jQuery and so far I have an idea of what to do. This is what I got:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mw-normal-catlinks a.first').replaceWith('Categories');
</script>
```

Now I am not sure if I am missing anything because when i put this in my HTML code, nothing happens. I'm not sure if I need to add a div to make it work.

I want to eventually implement this into a PHP coded tool I use to convert wiki pages to html so maybe I will need to add some sort of div?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('#mw-normal-catlinks a.first').contents().unwrap();
```

Also you probably want this selector instead since your `a` tag doesn't have a class of `.first`:

```
$('#mw-normal-catlinks a:first-child').contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

`.first` means *"A member of the class `first`"*, you might be confusing it with `:first-child` or `:first-of-type`